# Inverting audio in Java

Tags: java, android, audio

I am new to Java and I want to know how to invert audio (fixed voice inversion) coming from the input through a loopback to the output after a delay. How and where would I do this, and would I be able to set a frequency of the inversion somehow. Thanks.

```
package net.bitplane.android.microphone;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MicrophoneService extends Service implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    
    private static final String APP_TAG = "Microphone";
    private static final int mSampleRate = 44100;
    private static final int mFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    
    private AudioTrack mAudioOutput;
    private AudioRecord mAudioInput;
    private int mInBufferSize;
    private int mOutBufferSize;
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private static boolean mActive = false;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private MicrophoneReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
    
    private class MicrophoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     // Turn the mic off when things get loud
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     String action = intent.getAction();
             if (action != null && action.equals(android.media.AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)) {
             
                     SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             
                     SharedPreferences.Editor e = prefs.edit();
                     e.putBoolean("active", false);
                     e.commit();
             }
     }
    }
    
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
    }
    
@Override
public void onCreate() {
        
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Creating mic service");
        
        // notification service
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        
        mBroadcastReceiver = new MicrophoneReceiver();
        
        // create input and output streams
    mInBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(mSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, mFormat);
    mOutBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(mSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, mFormat);
    mAudioInput = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, mSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, mFormat, mInBufferSize);
    mAudioOutput = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, mFormat, mOutBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        
        // listen for preference changes
        mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_TAG, MODE_PRIVATE);
        mSharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        mActive = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("active", false);
                 
        if (mActive)
                record();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Stopping mic service");
        
        // close the service
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        e.putBoolean("active", false);
        e.commit();
        
        // disable the listener
        mSharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        
        mAudioInput.release();
        mAudioOutput.release();
}

    @Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            super.onStart(intent, startId);
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Service sent intent");
            
            // if this is a stop request, cancel the recording
            if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
                    if (intent.getAction().equals("net.bitplane.android.microphone.STOP")) {
                            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Cancelling recording via notification click");
                            SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
             e.putBoolean("active", false);
             e.commit();
                    }
            }
    }

    
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            // intercept the preference change.
            
            if (!key.equals("active"))
                    return;
            
            boolean bActive = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("active", false);
            
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Mic state changing (from " + mActive + " to " + bActive + ")");
            
            if (bActive != mActive) {
            
                    mActive = bActive;
                    
                    if (mActive)
                            record();
                    
                    if (!mActive)
                            mNotificationManager.cancel(0);
            }
    }
    
    public void record() {
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                            
                            Context context = getApplicationContext();
                            CharSequence titleText = getString(R.string.mic_active);
                            CharSequence statusText = getString(R.string.cancel_mic);
             long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
             Intent cancelIntent = new Intent();
             cancelIntent.setAction("net.bitplane.android.microphone.STOP");
             cancelIntent.setData(Uri.parse("null://null"));
             cancelIntent.setFlags(cancelIntent.getFlags() | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);
             PendingIntent pendingCancelIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, cancelIntent, 0);
             Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.status, titleText, when);
                            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, titleText, statusText, pendingCancelIntent);
                            mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
                            
                            // allow the
                            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(android.media.AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY));
                            
                            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Entered record loop");
                            
                            recordLoop();
                            
                            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Record loop finished");
                    }
                    
                    private void recordLoop() {
                            if ( mAudioOutput.getState() != AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED || mAudioInput.getState() != AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                                    Log.d(APP_TAG, "Can't start. Race condition?");
                            }
                            else {
                                    
                                    try {
                                    
                                            try { mAudioOutput.play(); } catch (Exception e) { Log.e(APP_TAG, "Failed to start playback"); return; }
                                            try { mAudioInput.startRecording(); } catch (Exception e) { Log.e(APP_TAG, "Failed to start recording"); mAudioOutput.stop(); return; }
                                            
                                            try {
                                                    
                                     ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mInBufferSize);
                                     int o = 0;
                                     byte b[] = new byte[mInBufferSize];
                                     while(mActive) {
                                             o = mAudioInput.read(bytes, mInBufferSize);
                                             bytes.get(b);
                                             bytes.rewind();
                                             mAudioOutput.write(b, 0, o);
                                     }
                                    
                                     Log.d(APP_TAG, "Finished recording");
                                            }
                                            catch (Exception e) {
                                                    Log.d(APP_TAG, "Error while recording, aborting.");
                                            }
                    
                             try { mAudioOutput.stop(); } catch (Exception e) { Log.e(APP_TAG, "Can't stop playback"); mAudioInput.stop(); return; }
                             try { mAudioInput.stop(); } catch (Exception e) { Log.e(APP_TAG, "Can't stop recording"); return; }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e) {
                                            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Error somewhere in record loop.");                                
                                    }
                            }
                            // cancel notification and receiver
                            mNotificationManager.cancel(0);
                            try {
                                    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { Log.e(APP_TAG, "Receiver wasn't registered: " + e.toString()); }
                    }
            };
            
            t.start();
            
    }
}
```